# Autorefresh in Dashboard using ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm developing an application in Rails wich acts as a network and apps monitor. I'm using Active Admin Dashboard as a main page, showing the status of every server and some apps in my network. I'd like to configure the dashboard page to autorefresh every x minutes, but I don't know where to configure this setting, because I don't have full control of the html rendered by the dashboard. Have anyone managed to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **config/initializers/active_admin.rb** you can register javascripts:

```
config.register_javascript "/javascripts/admin-auto-refresh.js"
```

Then create a admin-auto-refresh.js that does exactly that.

You'll also want to register admin-auto-refresh.js in your config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += "admin-auto-refresh.js"
```

UPDATE:

Added some code to refresh the page after 5 seconds. Add this to `/javascripts/admin-auto-refresh.js`

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(location.reload(true), 5000);
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the final code, thanks very much to @JesseWolgamott.

```
$(function() {
var sPath = window.location.pathname;
    var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    if (sPage == 'admin'){
        setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 10000);
    }
})
```

Comment: Just another observation: if we write this code in assets\javascripts\active_admin.js then there's no need to register the javascript in active_admin.rb.

Answer (score 0):

Below is code that will refresh without the page flashing.  It is enabled by having at least one element in the page with a class tag of needs_updating.   Include this code snippet in any javascript that is loaded and then add the tag any where on the page.

The only downside is this ONLY updates the html body of the page.

For example

```
show do |my_model| 
  ...
  if my_model.processing?
    row :status, class: 'needs_updating' do
      'we are working on it...'
    end
  else
    row :status do
      'ready'
    end
  end
  ....
end
```

so if the model is still processing then you get the class tag 'needs_updating' which will cause the below javascript to be invoked every 10 seconds

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($('.needs_updating').length > 0) {
      console.log("we need some updating soon");
      var timer = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("re-loading now");
        $.ajax({
          url: "",
          context: document.body,
          success: function(s,x) {
              $(this).html(s);
              if ($('.needs_updating').length == 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
              }
          }
        });
      }, 10000)
    }
  })
```